# In the siege of Osaka, how long did Osaka Castle burn?

Tags: military, war, japan, castles

I've heard that [Osaka castle was burned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Osaka#The_fall_of_Osaka_Castle), and I was curious: How long would it take for a structure like this to burn down?  I haven't been able to find any records that say how long Osaka Castle burned and what was left afterwards.

Can anyone satisfy my curiosity?